# json does not include object name during stingify

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, dom

I am trying to convert a javascript object into json using `JSON.stringify()` method. My problem is that when it stingify the object , it only stingify the object's key and values.It does not include the object name.

I want the output like `{"Color" : "{"Name":"background","Type":"Color","Value":"Red"}"}` but the output comes is `{"Name":"background","Type":"Color","Value":"Red"}`.

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hMwjq/) .

I know that json works like this but i want the way to acheive this. Thanks in advance !

Comment: As you can see the answers given here, you can't specify a name for your Object, because objects does not have names, only `types` in many languages. A name for an Object is another Object property that you use to define it like an `id`, for example, or just to name it if it is not unique. If you want to define your name out of the object, you should use @JamesN answer. You must specify an object with a property called, `name` or whatever you want, define another property, called `color` or whatever you want, and add it as value your `color` Object. These are basics from Object Orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `createColor` function return an object with a property that contains the color object:

```
function createColor() {
  var color = new Color();
  color.Name = "background";
  color.Type = "Color";
  color.Value = "Red";

  return { Color: color };
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hMwjq/5/

Answer (score 6):

The object doesn't know its own name, so you need to explicitly name it in the JSON:

```
JSON.stringify({'Color': color});
```

Comment: i cant do it, because my original hierarchy is very large. There are so many children are there for each object.and children of children and so on. so i cant do it manually. it will take days to do so.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
(function () {
    var color = createColor();
    jsonObject = {};
    jsonObject.color = color;
    var json = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    console.log(json);
})();
```

see [full Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/james_nguyen/hMwjq/4/)